# Update single or multiple row with data from another row in the different table

Tags: php, mysql

Admin need to approve profile information only then it will be displayed.
For this my thought is we need to store the data in a dummy table and after reviewing it by the admin and approves it the data update occurs in the master user table.

So I need to update the master table row using the dummy table row. How to do it using simple update query?

Is there any other simpler method?

I doing it using PHP MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert it to the table like (if both tables are alike):

```
INSERT INTO MasterTable
  SELECT * FROM DummyTable
```

A suggestion from my side:

You can add a boolean column to the MasterTable like `IsApproved`. And set it to `false` by default.

When selecting records from it, use:

```
SELECT * FROM MasterTable WHERE IsApproved='true'
```

So users will not get those records which are not approved. When administrator approves each record, update that record and set `IsApproved` to `true`. i.e.,

```
UPDATE MasterTable
SET IsApproved='true'
Where ID=ItsID
```

So, now user user will be able to get that record.

Comment: @DixonMD: What is your doubt? In the Insert query or the second method?

Comment: Doubt in the second method.

Comment: @DixonMD: You want users to see only approved records, right? I will edit my answer.

Comment: If the user edited after the approval old record will be there and new record is inserted right?

Comment: @DixonMD: Its up to you, my friend. You can insert new record **OR** edit old record and change `IsApproved` to `false` again.